# How to add 2 buttons on each view in recyclerview

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, button, android-recyclerview, view

I have a working app that I want to upgrade a little. right now I am fetching an API from a web page with a list of many places that you can visit, and I list all the names from the page in recycler view in main. and when I click on a view, I am redirected to another page.

but what I want now is to have 2 buttons leading to each side.

like this:

if you tap on the name you will be sent to an information page and if you press the GPS icon you will be sent to google maps (I have implemented google maps). but I don't quite know how to do this

**This is my Adapter**

```
class MainAdapter(val homeFeed : HomeFeed) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {

private var TAG = "Main"

    // numberOfItems
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return homeFeed.features.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        // how do we even create a view
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false)

        return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val feature = homeFeed.features.get(position)

        holder.view.textView_place_name.text = feature.properties.name
        holder.feature = feature
    }
}

class CustomViewHolder(val view: View, var feature: Feature? = null): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    companion object{
        val FEATURE_NAME_KEY = "FEATURE_TITLE"
        val FEATURE_ID_KEY = "FEATURE_ID"
    }

    init {

        view.setOnClickListener {
            println("clicking on a view : MainAdapter")

            val intent = Intent(view.context, DetailActivity::class.java)

            intent.putExtra(FEATURE_NAME_KEY,feature?.properties?.name)
            intent.putExtra(FEATURE_ID_KEY, feature?.properties?.id)

            view.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
   }
}// end CustomViewHolder
```

this is my "view":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_navigation_link"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_place_name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_place_name"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_map_marker" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_place_name"
    android:background="@drawable/rd_corners_list_row"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Place Name"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

It is this "imageView_navigation_link" I want to add a second button, but I don't know how to change my adapter to achieve this.

if you can help me make it clickable along with textView_place_name I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val feature = homeFeed.features.get(position)

    holder.view.textView_place_name.text = feature.properties.name
    holder.view.imageView_navigation_link.setOnclickListener{
        // do your logic here
    }

    holder.feature = feature
}
```